# 'Compactness' vs 'Closed and bounded' for general metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

We know that for $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, A is closed & bounded $\iff$ A is compact and that this does not generalize to general metric spaces.

> > 1.) For which class of metric spaces, is 'closed & bounded' equivalent to compactness.

Now there is another related question :

> > 2.) Suppose $(X,d)$ is an arbitrary metric space. Is it possible to find another metric $d'$ such that the induced topologies by $d$ and $d'$ are the same and A $\subset$ X, A is compact $\iff$ A is closed and bounded w.r.t. $d'$.

In some cases it is indeed possible to do so e.g. let $X$= set of all points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with integer coordinates and $d$ be the discrete metric. Then compactness is not equivalent to 'closed & bounded w.r.t. the metric $d$. But now let $d'$ be the metric induced from the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $d'$ does the job above. This example leads me to wonder if this can always be done.

Comment: Note that based on a metric $d$ you can always define a metric $d'\left(x,y\right)=\min\left\{ d\left(x,y\right),1\right\} $.
The generated topologies of $d$ and $d'$ are the same, but you will
have $d'\left(x,y\right)\leq1$ for any pair $\left(x,y\right)$.

Answer (score 6):

The answer to the second question is that it’s not always possible. Let $X$ be an uncountable discrete space, and fix $x\in X$. Let $d$ be any metric on $X$ generating the discrete topology. For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $A_n=\{y\in X:d(x,y)\le n\}$. Clearly some $A_n$ must be infinite (in fact uncountable), and that $A_n$ is a closed, bounded set that is not compact.

I suspect that there is no really nice answer to the first question. Note that if $X$ is metrizable, there is always a bounded compatible metric, so if $X$ is not compact, it always has a compatible metric with respect to which some bounded, closed subset is not compact.

Comment: This might help with the first question.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space

Comment: @Stephen: It’s possible, but I doubt that there really is a nice answer to the first question.